# Unable to open HTML link from HTML homepage

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

When running on node server, I get the error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, when I try to access a second page of HTML from the home page.

Directory:
-Login_Page_V2.html
-Forgot_Password_V1.html
-Login_Page_V1.js

HTML:

```html
<a href="http://flip.engr.oregonstate.edu:6772/Forgot_Password_V1.html" style="text-decoration: none">Forgot your password?</a>
```

Javascript:

```js
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/Forgot_Password_V1.html', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + './Forgot_Password_V1.html');
```

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/nfs/stak/users/username/folder/nodepage./Forgot_Password_V1.html'
>       at Error (native)

Comment: Check the path correctly

Answer (score 0):

Change this `response.sendFile(__dirname + './Forgot_Password_V1.html');`
to `response.sendFile(__dirname + '/Forgot_Password_V1.html');`.

Notice the dot.

`'./Forgot_Password_V1.html'` and `'/Forgot_Password_V1.html'`.